# Find command in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find

Okay so I am running a simple command like this:

```
find / -name ssh | grep bin
```

the output of that is this:

```
/usr/bin/ssh
```

Now I want to make it look like this for when I cd to it

```
/usr/bin/
```

I can't figure out how to make it smart because I can brute force it to work only for this one, but what about when I want to run this same code on a different machine and the location of ssh is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you trying to find ssh in your path? Does this server have something like mlocate installed?

Comment: I see that no one has asked the obvious question: why are you trying to `cd` to the location of the ssh executable?

Comment: well the use of ssh was a simple example I have a program that i want to execute and its in a directory that i cant locate if i do the brute force method.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see the need to `cd` to the corresponding directory.  Once you've found it, just execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you want this?

```
cd $(dirname $(which ssh));
```

Comment: How about explaining what each bit does in the above?

Comment: Hm, what [dirname](http://www.google.com/search?q=man+dirname), [which](http://www.google.com/search?q=man+which) or [cd](http://www.google.com/search?q=man+cd)? Or shells.. could be shells that need explaining, hmm...

Comment: I was thinking the semicolon.

Comment: Ah, that, that is because I have the dirty, dirty habit of running multiple commands on one line..  I blame the lemonade I spilled on my enter key 2 months ago.

Comment: It's only a dirty habit if you're using `;` and not `&&`

Comment: But... that would mean I _care_ about what the first command does... I wouldn't give it the satisfaction, if that arrogant bunch of bytes doesn't want to comply it can just bugger off, plenty of fish in the sea... (but you're right of course ;) )

Comment: $(<expression>) executes the expression in the current shell.

Answer (score 2):

Is dirname what you're looking for?

```
$ dirname `find / -name ssh | grep bin | head -1`
/usr/bin
```

The `head -1` part is only to make sure only 1 thing gets passed to dirname, otherwise it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find where the `ssh` command lives you have several options:

```
  which ssh
```

and

```
  whereis ssh
```

will give you this information (`which` will give you a single path, while `whereis` will contain paths with all references to `ssh`)

As for the `find` command, change the (starting) directory you specify in the `find` command:

```
  find /usr/bin -name ssh
```

will start its search in the /usr/bin directory.

Is this what you are trying to do? I'm not 100% sure I understood the last part of your post. If not, could you consider rephrasing it please?

Comment: see thats the thing it might not even be located in /usr/ directory it could be anywhere.

Comment: You don't need the `| grep bin` because all results will have a `bin` in it

Comment: maybe its my lack of experience but the thing is it might not be in the usr directory is what i meant. like it could be in the var directory or something else

Comment: @shade917 so then starting the search in `/` was the right thing to do. I am still not quite sure what you are trying to do, if you have any clarifying comments, you may want to put them into your original question since not everyone reads all of the comments. Are you trying to find the location of a given command? Why did the output of `find` not suit you in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -name ssh|grep bin|xargs dirname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **xargs** to obtain directory portion of the command.

```
find / | filter1 | xargs -I_VAR_ dirname _VAR_
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -name ssh | grep bin|sed "s/ssh//g"
```

Answer (score 0):

The *dirname* program, part of the coreutils, may be used to strip off the last part in the pathname sequence:

```
dirname `find / -name ssh | grep bin`
```

will output

```
/usr/bin
```

then.